# c++ How to make multidimentional vector from a table in a text file?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to store the following table to a multidimentional vector in c++ so that I can call the value by the column names. Here is my table:

```
  1 #kjflsj sjflskjf
  2 100.00 200.43
  3 101.23 198.56
  4 102.12 201.87
  5 99.67 198.28
  6 #sfjslkdjf lsfjls jf jslkfjsij osiioj o
  7 100.54 205.98
  8 99.87 199.34
  9 101.57 202.75
 10 103.10 193.50
 11 101.78 198.33
 12 102.13 204.75
 13 #slifjsf ojfosij  oiuiso  joij
 14 104.56 208.34
 15 106.14 199.50
 16 105.98 200.00
```

And here are my codes:

```
 16     ifstream myfile;
 17     myfile.open (arguments[1]);
 18     string line;
 19     string sline;
 20     vector< vector<double> > values;
 21     double x;

 24 if (myfile.is_open())
 25     {
 26         getline(myfile, sline);
 27         cout << sline << endl;
 28         while (!myfile.eof())
 29         {
 30             if(line.at(0) != '#')
 31             {
 32                 myfile >> x;
 33                 values.push_back(vector<double>(x));
 34
 35                 for(int count = 0; count < values.size(); count++)
 36                 {
 37                     values.push_back( vector<double>(count) );
 38                     cout << values.at(0).at(0);
 39                 }
 40             }
 41         }
 42     }else cout << "The file doesn't exist" << endl;
 43 }
```

The error I got:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well `for(int count = 0; count < values.size(); count++)` is an infinite loop. Both `count` and `values.size()` increase by one every iteration.

Comment: @Barry, that deserves to be promoted to an answer.

Comment: I'd assume that the exception is thrown on line 30, because `line` is an empty string. But the snippet you've posted doesn't give much information about that variable. Additionally you have the problem Barry already stated and your check if `myfile` is in a valid state isn't done properly.

Comment: I just made a "string sline" in the main function and some other double variables. nothing more. Would you please tell me how to fix it? I'm pretty new to c++

Comment: I'm talking about `if(line.at(0) != '#')`. That variable is called `line`, not `sline`. But I've seen, that you also have a variable called `sline`.

Comment: yes, I also made a string line.

Comment: And I assume that `line` is an empty string. I can't say for sure because your code snippet isn't complete, but it's the only statement in your snippet at which this exception can be thrown.

Comment: The codes have been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the exception is likely:

```
getline(myfile, sline);   // <== reading into "sline"
while (!myfile.eof())
{
    if(line.at(0) != '#') // <== checking "line"
    {
```

You're reading into one `string`, but checking the wrong one!

The correct check would be:

```
while (getline(myfile, sline)) {
    if (sline.at(0) != '#') {
        // note that before, for non-commented lines, you
        // just dropped sline completely, and went back to the
        // file for input. That is wrong, you need to 
        // parse the line you just got!

        std::vector<double> next_row;
        std::istringstream iss(sline);
        while (iss >> x) {
            next_row.push_back(x);
        }

        // etc.
    }
}
```

Once that is fixed, it's not obvious, but this loop:

```
for(int count = 0; count < values.size(); count++)
{
    values.push_back( vector<double>(count) );
    cout << values.at(0).at(0);
}
```

is actually an infinite loop if `values` is non-empty. This is because on every iteration, we insert an element into `values`, which increases its size. So both `count` and `values.size()` increment by one every iteration - you're constantly moving the goal posts. That is a serious logical error.

Comment: Another logical error is that his call to `getline` has to be within the `while`-loop and the `failbit` of `myfile` has to be checked after having read from `myfile`.

Comment: Thanks, Barry. Once I push back "values.push_back(vector<double>(x));" What should I do next?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, foobar. I just want to print the first line of the file as a title.

Comment: @Gray Well, don't do `values.push_back(vector<double>(x));` That line makes no sense, it calls [constructor #2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) from this reference, and that's just not at all what you intended. Just build up your row one `double` at a time (like I show in my answer), and then add that row to your list.

Comment: Great, Barry! I'm trying.